# 'Friend' wants my job. I don't want to work with her. Is there a professional way to avoid it?

Tags: hiring

Some 'friend' of mine wants my job. She has high technical expertise and a dreadful personality: others' success is a personal offense, and I suspect she resents me because I got a job she wanted.
She became a customer, and I had awful, aggressive communications from her side so far. She has been skipping me to get other colleagues support, trying to build relationships with my colleagues as a customer (a demanding customer). I already told my manager I am uncomfortable with this customer (while working with the team to make sure the customer's company is happy).

This person is going so far as giving my contact to others for random jobs.

The company is growing, and technically this person might help. My bosses might think 'we need a developer soon, this person already knows our company's technology, good'. However, I think I would be undermined on a daily basis by her, and I don't feel comfortable having her in my same team. The company has a very friendly culture, but my boss might just want to hire somebody quickly.

Is there any way I can avoid getting this person hired?

Comment: You say she wants your job. What's your position title and what are your duties in that position? I am asking you for this info because her emails to you could be used against her - you didn't delete those emails, right? - depending on what your duties are. You say that she's been very aggressive in her emails to you. Given that your company is a very friendly company, I see an argument for lack of fit on her part right there.

Comment: How is this person a friend? Seems like more of a manipulative and malicious acquaintance at best.

Comment: She is a very opinionated coder waiting for the big chance of her life. She resents not being promoted and others' success. The kind of smart person you don't want around. She lost an amazing job early in her career because she didn't get promoted quickly enough.

Comment: If she keeps sharing your contact information, people will ask you about her. You can always say that you would not feel comfortable working with her, or that you did not give her permission to share your contact information.

Comment: How did she lose a job from not being promoted quickly enough?  Did she quit?  That's not losing a job, that's her being stupid.

Comment: high performing team member didn't get promoted. translation: if she didn't get promoted, then I won't get promoted soon. arguement with team leader, left dream job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider asking your boss if you can be part of the hiring panel when they get another developer. Then you have a say in the final decision.

I would also have a talk with my boss about how this person seems to be looking to get a developer job at your place of work and why that idea makes you uncomfortable. Any hiring panel I have ever been on has taken into consideration how well the person would fit with existing personnel (it is the most important criteria after determining if the person can do the job at all) and if they know the person and don't give a high recommendation to hire, generally we pass.

Comment: +1 whenever anyone knows a potential recruit, I'm interested in their opinions of them good or bad, and if they say "this is a toxic person and I don't think they'll be a good part of the team here" that just about settles it.

Answer (score 8):

You say she has an awful personality, and is playing political games to get what she wants, and you might suffer from that. I propose you do a bit of that yourself.

If you have any "normal" conversations with your boss, mention what an awful customer you have. Obviously you are *completely* unaware that your boss might be looking for a different employee. Give some examples not of demanding, but of unreasonable behaviour, like complaining about perfectly fine deliveries, creating cost by changing her mind, and so on. Just give an impression that this is a person that nobody in their right mind would want near them, and have a good moan about her.

Especially if your company has a very friendly culture, that is something worth a lot, and your boss would think twice to risk that being destroyed, if he or she is aware of the danger. But if you think being objective and stating facts is better, have a look at politics.

Answer (score 5):

If you're asked what you think, be objective and state facts. Demonstrate them with evidence where possible.

Beyond that, there is nothing you can do to influence the decision which isn't risking backlash from this "friend" or your employer or the law or some combination of them all.

Answer (score 1):

You've already communicated to your boss that you aren't comfortable with this person.

She's already going around you and has established a relationship with others she is working with for being difficult.

Seems to me that you've already done what you need to in planting the seed that she might not be the best person make part of the team. Your company *has* to deal with her now because she works for a customer, but if she's difficult, probably no one is going to say "wow, she needs to be difficult, here, for us all the time and make that impression upon others as part of our team."

The company would consider such a move if, in her dealing with your company, people are highly impressed and like working with her.  If someone were floating the idea, generally, and didn't know much about her, they'd ask the people she does deal with regularly how she is.

Seems to me, that (A) you're really not in a position to personally stop this, (B) you've already done what you can while still staying professional, and (C) there's no way others are going to be clamoring to bring her on board, in fact, if she has a reputation for being difficult, the opposite recommendation will probably be offered.

Hopefully your company doesn't have a penchant for shooting itself in the foot.  I'd guess you should be fine, other than getting passive-aggressively harassed by proxy by having every recruiter in the world bothering you.